# Short way? Write taylor's formula $f(x,y)=e^{xy}$ $a=(0,0)$ and $p=4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Write taylor's formula $f(x,y)=e^{xy}$ $a=(0,0)$ and $p=4$

Does there exist any short way? I have to calculate all partial dervatives. Is it?

Comment: Note that the partial derivatives will involve factors of $x$ and $y$, and so the higher-order terms will be zero, except the fourth, where you have to write the remainder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short way is to use the well known one-dimensional result: The 4th dergree taylor polynomial of $e^t$ is $$T_4=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}+\frac{t^4}{24}.$$
All you have to do is to plug in $t=xy$ to get 
$$T_4=1+xy+\frac{x^2y^2}{2}+\frac{x^3y^3}{6}+\frac{x^4y^4}{24}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: The partial derivatives are given by

$$ \frac{\partial^{m+n} }{\partial x^ny^m}e^{xy} = y^nx^me^{xy} $$

Comment: It should be $\frac {\partial^{n+m}}{\partial x^n y^m}$

Comment: That is true, it is now fixed :)